# Cannot render boolean value in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render boolean value inside JSX, however React is evaluating it as expression and isn't returning anything after the component is returned.

Any workaround for this?

Here is an example

```
var ipsumText = true;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     Boolean Value:    {ipsumText}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('impl')
);
```

Just shows compiled HTML as

```
<div data-reactid=".0"><span data-reactid=".0.0">Boolean Value:    </span></div>
```

**EDIT:** Here is the JSBin link for the example http://jsbin.com/nibihodoce/1/edit?html,js,output

**EDIT 2:** I have already explored the .toString() alternative, however since I am iterating over an array of objects and a particular field of that object can have string/integer/boolean kind of value. Applying .toString() to all of 'em doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: "Applying .toString() to all of 'em doesn't seem optimal" -- Use `{ String( value ) }` then. Nothing is more optimal and universal than that.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
Boolean Value: { ipsumText.toString() }
```

or

```
Boolean Value: { String(ipsumText) }
```

or

```
Boolean Value: { '' + ipsumText }
```

or

```
{`Boolean Value: ${ipsumText}`}
```

or

```
Boolean Value: { JSON.stringify(ipsumText) }
```

I prefer the second option. Universal, fast, works for all primitive types:  `Boolean( smth )`, `Number( smth )`.

Comment: Why do we need do type cast? why can't boolean show directly?

Comment: React doesn't allow object as values, But [Vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ovzhdn) does show the actual values apart from undefined and null. I belilve it's using `toString` underhood but why react won't do that?

Comment: @Naren Angular works the same as in Vue in this regard, which I think is the desirable default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert boolean value to string, concatenating it with empty string:

```
var ipsumText = true;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     Boolean Value: {ipsumText + ''}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('impl')
);
```

Or you can do it, when assigning `bool` value to variable:

```
var ipsumText = true + '';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     Boolean Value: {ipsumText}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('impl')
);
```

If your variable can have not boolean value, you should convert it to boolean:

```
// `ipsumText` variable is `true` now.
var ipsumText = !!'text';
```

Comment: In case the value isn't boolean, I would wish to show it as is.

Comment: In this case, use this condition:
`var ipsumText = typeof value === 'boolean' ? value + '' : value;`
We are checking if variable is boolean, when we are converting it to string, else displaying it as is.

Answer (score 2):

@gaperton's answer is fantastic. I have another solution. here it is:

```
{ipsumText?'true':'false'}
```

Comment: I think because of how the problem got edited it lost some context. `ipsumText` isn't supposed to be boolean all the time, it could be string as well. We don't know it upfront what data type we shall be getting.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<select>
    <option value={row.feature_product ? true: true || row.feature_product ? false: false}>
    {`${row.feature_product}`}
    </option>
    <option value={row.feature_product ? false: true || row.feature_product ? true: false}>
    {`${row.feature_product ? false: true}` || `${row.feature_product ? true: false}`}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.