# Back button react native doesnt closes the app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hi im trying to do this:

1- i have a basic webview app, when i press back button i should get back to last page but if im on login page and press back button or back gesture on my android my app should exit, but is not working it stays open when i press back button it refresh the webview again and again here my code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    flex: 1
  }
})
export default class App extends Component {
  webView = {
    canGoBack: false,
    ref: null,

  }
  onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
      this.webView.ref.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onAndroidBackPress);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
  }, 1800);

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.flexContainer}>
       <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://clientes.dbsnetwork.net'}}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
        renderLoading={() => (
          <ActivityIndicator
            color='black'
            size='large'
            style={styles.flexContainer}
          />
        )}
        style={{marginTop: 0}}
        ref={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => { this.webView.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack; }}
      />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

}
```

there is anything else i should do?

attached video gif

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function looks not go to exit the app.

It should be like this:(Edit your partial code)

```js
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

...
onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
        BackHandler.exitApp(); //Function to exit the App
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
...
```

Comment: yes i tried that, but then after i login to my website and press back button it exists instead of navigating to the previews page.

Comment: thats why i tried  this.webView.ref.goBack(); so when im navigating in my website i can go back to last page

Comment: Could you try to remove the condition? Just let it close to try function works? Because it looks something wrong of the `this.webView.canGoBack`, If  remove the condition and it works, you could find out the problem.

Comment: So the problem is not exit app function, is at the condition. It looks `canGoBack` always `false` or `webView.ref` problem. You could `console.log` each of them before if condition. And then trace out the wrong setting.

Comment: Would `onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => { this.webView.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack; }}` set `this.webView.canGoBack ` to true? and cause the if condition pass?  I'm not sure I have seen where setting `canGoBack ` to true to pass the condition. So if possible, `console.log` `canGoBack` and `webView.ref` will be the fast action to debug.

Comment: If `console.log` is hard in your environment, you could use `Alert.alert` to [show](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) each of them, is the same result. Don't forget to import it.

Comment: yes i tried   onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
      this.webView.ref.goBack();
Alert.alert("this.props.nav.index",this.webView.canGoBack);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } but not working

Comment: value from message cannot be cast from boolean to string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337262/cannot-render-boolean-value-in-jsx

Or you could just change your android press to a simple condition: `if(this.webView.canGoBack){Alert(canGoBack is true)}else if(this.webView.ref){Alert(ref is true)}else {Alert(all false)}`  and change something what you want to know....  The word alert is simplify, you have to write correct way not only copy it.

Answer (score 0):

**onNavigationStateChange**: event has the following

```
{"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "loading": false, "target": 3, "title": "Property Management System", "url": "https://something.com/analytics-app/"}
```

**webview** reference has this:

```
{"current": {"clearCache": [Function clearCache], "clearFormData": [Function clearFormData], "clearHistory": [Function clearHistory], "goBack": [Function goBack], "goForward": [Function goForward], "injectJavaScript": [Function injectJavaScript], "postMessage": [Function postMessage], "reload": [Function reload], "requestFocus": [Function requestFocus], "stopLoading": [Function stopLoading]}}
```

For [android](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md), the solution given in the docs is:

```
const webViewRef = useRef(null);
const onAndroidBackPress = () => {
  if (webViewRef.current) {
    webViewRef.current.goBack();
    return true; // prevent default behavior (exit app)
  }
  return false;
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBackPress);
    };
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: If this does not work for you and you are using a single page web application, consider this conversation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7602