# Cannot display prop value from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I am trying to display the prop value that I receive from the redux store via mapStateToProps. However, when I tried to display the prop value to the browser, it's empty. If I use JSON.stringify() to do so, the value will appear. Moreover, console logging the prop shows that there is a value. So, why do I need to use JSON.stringify to display the prop value?

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/actions/auth';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Login = ({ login, auth }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>isAuthenticated: {JSON.stringify(auth.isAuthenticated)}</p>

      {/* Why can't I just display the prop value as it is? */}
      <p>isAuthenticated: {auth.isAuthenticated}</p>
    </>
  );
};

// Prop validation
Login.prototypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

Comment: Maybe because it's an object it doesn't re-render when the reference change, but the pointer still points to the mew state

Comment: @ItayTur Hi, If I change the object to a boolean, the issue still remains the same

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337262/cannot-render-boolean-value-in-jsx

Comment: Can you show the reducer and the provider

Comment: @Anthony I understand now, thank you. How do I close this question?

Comment: I think at the bottom of the question there should be a delete link