# Printing state value in React which is boolean doesn't get printed by String Interpolation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ButtonStatus1 extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: "false",
      b: false
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>a: {this.state.a}, b: {this.state.b}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonStatus1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected:**

false, false

String Interpolation, as far as I know, will always output in form of string, whatever the input is. So, in that scenario, even if `this.state.b` was a boolean - `false`, the output should have been printed. If the value is there -- just because it was boolean, why is it not printed. Isn't this strange??

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337262/cannot-render-boolean-value-in-jsx? 

I think React does not coerce values to strings. It's not strictly string interpolation here, rather React is executing an expression inside of `{}`.

Comment: Have you tried to add the .toString() method? Values should print properly with this.state.a.toString().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is not just string interpolation

It is a JSX syntax to inform that the expression inside it needs to be evaluated

But there are some specific values for which nothing will be rendered, like

```
<div />

<div></div>

<div>{false}</div>

<div>{null}</div>

<div>{undefined}</div>

<div>{true}</div>
```

and booleans are often used for conditional rendering like

```
{array.length > 0 && array.map(...)}
```

if `array.length > 0` is `false`, rendering `false` is not desirable

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)

---

btw, you can convert the booleans to strings if you want to render them (`false.toString()`)

Answer (score 2):

JSX is executing an expression inside of `{}`, it's not string interpolation.

If React **DID** print booleans/nulls/undefined, it would mean you could not do short circuits like:

```
isTrue() && <p>hello world</p>
```

Instead of rendering nothing if `isTrue()` equals `false`, it would always render `false` in the DOM. This would make conditional rendering much more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Into React world return false has the same result as return null. So string interpolation it is simple function that return NOT only strings. It can be any rendered JSX component. That's why false rendered as empty value. You should use

```
String(this.state.b);
```